# Sliding one layout on another in android

Tags: android, slide, sliding, jfeinstein

I need to slide one layout on another in android.

Requirments.

**1** . **layout1** covers 80% of the screen and the rest is occupied by **layout 2**.

[image]

**2** . I need to be able to **slide** **layout 2** on top of **layout 1**, 
    total width or scrollable limit for layout 2 should be such that
    **20% of layout 1** should be visible below.

[image]

**3** . Then i need to slide **layout 2 back** to its original position.

[image]

I have tried may sliding tutorials including

[Sliding Menu by Jfeinstein](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu)

[Slide Panel Layout - Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SlidingPaneLayout.html)

and many other tutorials available in the internet.

None of these was able to provide what i need, i tried many customizations and spent almost a week,

could someone help.

Comment: Have you tried Viewpager : http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Comment: thanks @vjdhama , i will try this and let you know.

Comment: how about you try looking at some Sliding Menu libraries? [link](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) among others

Comment: @vjdhama I tried it, but the second layout when slided covers the whole window, i want it to cover only 3/4 th of the window.

Comment: @user1481694 I tried it, but the second layout when slided covers the whole window, i want it to cover only 3/4 th of the window.

Comment: yes, that should be okay, because there should be a function there where you can set how much of the main screen can the sliding layout cover.. try slidingLayout.<ctrl+space> and lookup offset

Comment: Take a look at this : http://blog.neteril.org/blog/2013/10/10/framelayout-your-best-ui-friend/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got It!!.. Simplicity at its best. No libraries, No complicated codes. Use SimplePaneLayout.

Just set the android:layout_marginLeft to a suitable value. :) Awesome :)

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/slidingpanelayout">

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:background="#CCC"
                  android:orientation="horizontal"
                  android:id="@+id/fragment_firstpane"/>

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:background="#000"
                  android:orientation="horizontal"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                  android:id="@+id/fragment_secondpane"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout>
```